# Return the provider with the most visits out of the past 7 visits for each patient each month

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently have a dataset of 'visits' with the day, patient, provider, the rank of the appointment (sequential number of that appointment for that patient) and rank of the appointment/provider (sequential number of that appointment for that patient/provider)

Need to use this to do a lookback on the first of each month (1/1/2020 start), for each patient look at the prior 7 visits (with no limit on how far this is) and grab the provider that had the majority of those visits to associate with that patient for that month.

If the patient only had less than 7 visits, still apply this logic.
If the patient has an even number of visits that leads to a tie of these providers, the winner will be the most recent one.
Patients may not have any appointments for that month period.

So for example patient 'A' the base data is like this...

```
ApptDate | Patient | Provider | ApptRank | ApptProvRank |
1/15/2020|    A    |    BOB   |    1     |      1       |
3/01/2020|    A    |    BOB   |    2     |      2       |
3/08/2020|    A    |    BOB   |    3     |      3       |
3/20/2020|    A    |    BOB   |    4     |      4       |
4/01/2020|    A    |    BOB   |    5     |      5       |
4/15/2020|    A    |    SMITH |    6     |      1       |
6/07/2020|    A    |    SMITH |    7     |      2       |
6/21/2020|    A    |    BOB   |    8     |      6       |
7/01/2020|    A    |    JANE  |    9     |      1       |
7/15/2020|    A    |    JANE  |    10    |      2       |
7/21/2020|    A    |    JANE  |    11    |      3       |
8/01/2020|    A    |    JANE  |    12    |      4       |
8/15/2020|    A    |    JANE  |    13    |      5       |
9/20/2020|    A    |    JANE  |    14    |      6       |
```

I then have a process that fills in missing months and counts the number of appts within that month for each provider and that looks like this...

```
Month    | Patient | Provider |   Appts    |Cumulative Appt Rank | Cumulative Appt Provider Rank
1/1/2020 |     A   |    BOB   |     1      |   1                 |   1
2/1/2020 |     A   |    NULL  |    NULL    |  NULL               |   NULL
3/1/2020 |     A   |    BOB   |     3      |   4                 |   4
4/1/2020 |     A   |    BOB   |     1      |   5                 |   5
4/1/2020 |     A   |    SMITH |     1      |   6                 |   1
5/1/2020 |     A   |    NULL  |    NULL    |  NULL               |   NULL
6/1/2020 |     A   |    SMITH |     1      |   7                 |   2
6/1/2020 |     A   |    BOB   |     1      |   8                 |   6
7/1/2020 |     A   |    JANE  |     3      |   11                |   3
8/1/2020 |     A   |    JANE  |     2      |   13                |   5
9/1/2020 |     A   |    JANE  |     2      |   14                |   6
```

What I want is something that looks like this: (ONE month ONE provider and the share of Appts out of the 7 prior - which should never be higher than 7)

```
Month    | Patient | Provider | Appt Count (of Past 7)
2/1/2020 |     A   |    BOB   |     1      |            ----\> starting 2/1/2020 for the 'lookback'
3/1/2020 |     A   |    BOB   |     1      |
4/1/2020 |     A   |    BOB   |     4      |
5/1/2020 |     A   |    BOB   |     5      |  
6/1/2020 |     A   |    BOB   |     5      |  
7/1/2020 |     A   |    BOB   |     5      |  
8/1/2020 |     A   |    JANE  |     3      |  
9/1/2020 |     A   |    JANE  |     5      |  
10/1/2020|     A   |    JANE  |     6      |
```

This would involve multiple patients, but to simplify for this example it's just one. Greatly appreciate any help on this one

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so please show us. And please add your sample data as DDL+DML so we can copy and paste and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After converting your example data into DDL/DML:

```
DECLARE @Visits TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, ApptDate DATETIME, Patient NVARCHAR(10), Provider NVARCHAR(10), ApptRank INT, ApptProvRank INT);
INSERT INTO @Visits (ApptDate, Patient, Provider, ApptRank, ApptProvRank) VALUES
('1/15/2020',    'A',    'BOB   ',    1 ,      1),
('3/01/2020',    'A',    'BOB   ',    2 ,      2),
('3/08/2020',    'A',    'BOB   ',    3 ,      3),
('3/20/2020',    'A',    'BOB   ',    4 ,      4),
('4/01/2020',    'A',    'BOB   ',    5 ,      5),
('4/15/2020',    'A',    'SMITH ',    6 ,      1),
('6/07/2020',    'A',    'SMITH ',    7 ,      2),
('6/21/2020',    'A',    'BOB   ',    8 ,      6),
('7/01/2020',    'A',    'JANE  ',    9 ,      1),
('7/15/2020',    'A',    'JANE  ',    10,      2),
('7/21/2020',    'A',    'JANE  ',    11,      3),
('8/01/2020',    'A',    'JANE  ',    12,      4),
('8/15/2020',    'A',    'JANE  ',    13,      5),
('9/20/2020',    'A',    'JANE  ',    14,      6),

('1/15/2021',    'B',    'BOB   ',    1 ,      1),
('3/01/2021',    'B',    'BOB   ',    2 ,      2),
('3/08/2021',    'B',    'BOB   ',    3 ,      3),
('3/20/2021',    'B',    'BOB   ',    4 ,      4),
('4/01/2021',    'B',    'BOB   ',    5 ,      5),
('4/15/2021',    'B',    'SMITH ',    6 ,      1),
('6/07/2021',    'B',    'SMITH ',    7 ,      2),
('6/21/2021',    'B',    'JANE  ',    8 ,      6),
('7/01/2021',    'B',    'JANE  ',    9 ,      1),
('7/15/2021',    'B',    'JANE  ',    10,      2),
('7/21/2021',    'B',    'JANE  ',    11,      3),
('8/01/2021',    'B',    'JANE  ',    12,      4),
('8/15/2021',    'B',    'JANE  ',    13,      5),
('9/20/2021',    'B',    'JANE  ',    14,      6);
```

We can look at this data via windowed functions to determine the most popular provider for a patient over the last 7 visits (regardless of duration) and then  join back to it to see the most popular provider for the 7 visit window for each appointment.

```
;WITH top7VisitProvider AS (
SELECT patient, a.ApptRank, a.v7Provider, a.ProviderLast7Cnt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Patient, a.ApptRank ORDER BY a.ProviderLast7Cnt DESC) AS rn
  FROM (
        SELECT v.ID, v.ApptDate, v.Patient, v.Provider, v.ApptRank, v.ApptProvRank, vr.Provider AS v7Provider, COUNT(*) AS ProviderLast7Cnt
          FROM @Visits v
            LEFT OUTER JOIN @Visits vr
              ON v.Patient = vr.Patient
              AND vr.ApptRank BETWEEN v.ApptRank-7 AND v.ApptRank
        GROUP BY v.ID, v.ApptDate, v.Patient, v.Provider, v.ApptRank, v.ApptProvRank, vr.Provider
       ) a
)

SELECT v.ID, v.ApptDate, v.Patient, v.Provider, v.ApptRank, v.ApptProvRank, t7vp.v7Provider
  FROM @Visits v
    INNER JOIN top7VisitProvider t7vp
      ON v.Patient = t7vp.Patient
      AND v.ApptRank = t7vp.ApptRank
      AND t7vp.rn = 1
```

```
ID  ApptDate                Patient Provider    ApptRank    ApptProvRank    v7Provider
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   2020-01-15 00:00:00.000 A       BOB         1           1               BOB   
2   2020-03-01 00:00:00.000 A       BOB         2           2               BOB   
3   2020-03-08 00:00:00.000 A       BOB         3           3               BOB   
4   2020-03-20 00:00:00.000 A       BOB         4           4               BOB   
5   2020-04-01 00:00:00.000 A       BOB         5           5               BOB   
6   2020-04-15 00:00:00.000 A       SMITH       6           1               BOB   
7   2020-06-07 00:00:00.000 A       SMITH       7           2               BOB   
8   2020-06-21 00:00:00.000 A       BOB         8           6               BOB   
9   2020-07-01 00:00:00.000 A       JANE        9           1               BOB   
10  2020-07-15 00:00:00.000 A       JANE        10          2               BOB   
11  2020-07-21 00:00:00.000 A       JANE        11          3               BOB   
12  2020-08-01 00:00:00.000 A       JANE        12          4               JANE  
13  2020-08-15 00:00:00.000 A       JANE        13          5               JANE  
14  2020-09-20 00:00:00.000 A       JANE        14          6               JANE  
15  2021-01-15 00:00:00.000 B       BOB         1           1               BOB   
16  2021-03-01 00:00:00.000 B       BOB         2           2               BOB   
17  2021-03-08 00:00:00.000 B       BOB         3           3               BOB   
18  2021-03-20 00:00:00.000 B       BOB         4           4               BOB   
19  2021-04-01 00:00:00.000 B       BOB         5           5               BOB   
20  2021-04-15 00:00:00.000 B       SMITH       6           1               BOB   
21  2021-06-07 00:00:00.000 B       SMITH       7           2               BOB   
22  2021-06-21 00:00:00.000 B       JANE        8           6               BOB   
23  2021-07-01 00:00:00.000 B       JANE        9           1               BOB   
24  2021-07-15 00:00:00.000 B       JANE        10          2               BOB   
25  2021-07-21 00:00:00.000 B       JANE        11          3               JANE  
26  2021-08-01 00:00:00.000 B       JANE        12          4               JANE  
27  2021-08-15 00:00:00.000 B       JANE        13          5               JANE  
28  2021-09-20 00:00:00.000 B       JANE        14          6               JANE
```

Comment: This got me most of the way there, thank you. But I needed it from the 1st of every month vs from every appointment - so I've condensed this onto the month of the maximum appointment date per appointment month. Then I'm able to bring in the prior months value to fill in for missing months. But regardless, the part that I was stuck on this helped solve. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Let's start by creating some example tables. I chose to create a table with the "years months of reference", with an additional column indicating the most ancient historical date. This historical column would not be necessary, but I put it here to simplify the queries.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bu_datalake.ReferenceDate;

CREATE table bu_datalake.ReferenceDate
(
MonthlyReferenceDate           Date,
MaxMonthlyReferenceDateHistory Date
);   

INSERT 
  INTO bu_datalake.ReferenceDate
VALUES ('2022-01-01',ADD_MONTHS('2022-01-01',-7)), 
       ('2022-02-01',ADD_MONTHS('2022-02-01',-7)),
       ('2022-03-01',ADD_MONTHS('2022-03-01',-7)),
       ('2022-04-01',ADD_MONTHS('2022-04-01',-7)),
       ('2022-05-01',ADD_MONTHS('2022-05-01',-7)),
       ('2022-06-01',ADD_MONTHS('2022-06-01',-7)),
       ('2022-07-01',ADD_MONTHS('2022-07-01',-7)),
       ('2022-08-01',ADD_MONTHS('2022-08-01',-7)),
       ('2022-09-01',ADD_MONTHS('2022-09-01',-7)),
       ('2022-10-01',ADD_MONTHS('2022-10-01',-7)),
       ('2022-11-01',ADD_MONTHS('2022-11-01',-7)),
       ('2022-12-01',ADD_MONTHS('2022-12-01',-7));

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bu_datalake.PatientProvider;

CREATE table bu_datalake.PatientProvider
(
ApptDate Date,
Patient  String,
Provider String
);
   
INSERT 
  INTO bu_datalake.PatientProvider
VALUES
('2022-01-15','A','BOB'),   
('2022-03-01','A','BOB'),   
('2022-03-08','A','BOB'),   
('2022-03-20','A','BOB'),   
('2022-04-01','A','BOB'),   
('2022-04-15','A','SMITH'), 
('2022-06-07','A','SMITH'), 
('2022-06-21','A','BOB'),   
('2022-07-01','A','JANE'),  
('2022-07-15','A','JANE'),  
('2022-07-21','A','JANE'),  
('2022-08-01','A','JANE'),  
('2022-08-15','A','JANE'),  
('2022-09-20','A','JANE')
```

Here is the content of the created tables:

```
SELECT * FROM bu_datalake.ReferenceDate;

MonthlyReferenceDate    MaxMonthlyReferenceDateHistory
----------------------------------------------------
2022-01-01            2021-06-01
2022-02-01            2021-07-01
2022-03-01            2021-08-01
2022-04-01            2021-09-01
2022-05-01            2021-10-01
2022-06-01            2021-11-01
2022-07-01            2021-12-01
2022-08-01            2022-01-01
2022-09-01            2022-02-01
2022-10-01            2022-03-01
2022-11-01            2022-04-01
2022-12-01            2022-05-01

SELECT * FROM bu_datalake.PatientProvider;

ApptDate        Patient   Provider
-----------------------------------------------------
2022-01-15    A         BOB         
2022-03-01    A         BOB         
2022-03-08    A         BOB         
2022-03-20    A         BOB         
2022-04-01    A         BOB         
2022-04-15    A         SMITH       
2022-06-07    A         SMITH       
2022-06-21    A         BOB         
2022-07-01    A         JANE        
2022-07-15    A         JANE        
2022-07-21    A         JANE        
2022-08-01    A         JANE        
2022-08-15    A         JANE        
2022-09-20    A         JANE
```

Let's consolidate the attendances by month of reference,
grouped by Patients and Providers. We are creating a column
name MostRecentApptDate cause maybe we will need it when
there are same number of Patient-Providers attendances
in the month:

```
SELECT TRUNC(ApptDate,'MM') As ApptMonthlyDate,        
       Patient,                                
       Provider,                               
       MAX(ApptDate) MostRecentApptDate,       
       COUNT(*) PatientProviderOccurences      
  FROM bu_datalake.PatientProvider             
 GROUP BY TRUNC(ApptDate,'MM'),Patient,Provider
 ORDER BY TRUNC(ApptDate,'MM'),Patient,Provider
 
ApptMonthlyDate Patient Provider    MostRecentApptDate  PatientProviderOccurences 
2022-01-01      A         BOB         2022-01-15            1
2022-03-01      A         BOB         2022-03-20            3
2022-04-01      A         BOB         2022-04-01            1
2022-04-01      A         SMITH     2022-04-15          1
2022-06-01      A         BOB         2022-06-21            1
2022-06-01      A         SMITH     2022-06-07          1
2022-07-01      A         JANE      2022-07-21          3
```

Now, I'm going to make a join between this query and the reference month table. The purpose of this is - for "each reference month" - we can identify which records I will have to consider in  my "ranking classification" (next steps). As this query can present duplicated records (since one attendance can be used in different
"monthly ranking classifications") I will only present part of these results (the query should return about 61 records):

```
SELECT REF.MonthlyReferenceDate,
       PAT.ApptMonthlyDate, 
       REF.MaxMonthlyReferenceDateHistory,
       PAT.MostRecentApptDate,       
       PAT.Patient,
       PAT.Provider,
       PAT.PatientProviderOccurences        
  FROM bu_datalake.ReferenceDate REF
  JOIN (SELECT TRUNC(ApptDate,'MM') As ApptMonthlyDate,        
               Patient,                                
               Provider,                               
               MAX(ApptDate) MostRecentApptDate,       
               COUNT(*) PatientProviderOccurences      
          FROM bu_datalake.PatientProvider             
         GROUP BY TRUNC(ApptDate,'MM'),Patient,Provider) PAT
 WHERE PAT.ApptMonthlyDate BETWEEN REF.MaxMonthlyReferenceDateHistory AND REF.MonthlyReferenceDate
 ORDER BY REF.MonthlyReferenceDate,PAT.Patient,PAT.Provider 
  
MonthlyReferenceDate    ApptMonthlyDate MaxMonthlyReferenceDateHistory  MostRecentApptDate  Patient Provider    PatientProviderOccurences
2022-01-01            2022-01-01        2021-06-01                      2022-01-15          A         BOB         1
2022-02-01            2022-01-01        2021-07-01                      2022-01-15          A         BOB         1
2022-03-01            2022-03-01        2021-08-01                      2022-03-20          A         BOB         3
```

Then, I will put in this query a additional column that will classify/rank de results, so I can then identify which are the most attendances by Monthly Reference date. We will use here a windown function called **"ROW_NUMBER"**. There are many others functions as **RANK**, **DENSE_RANK** and
*I advise you to study this topic as it is very useful to solve problems like this*. Again, I will provide only part of the query results:

```
SELECT REP.MonthlyReferenceDate,
       REP.Patient,
       REP.Provider,
       REP.PatientProviderOccurences,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY REP.MonthlyReferenceDate ORDER BY REP.PatientProviderOccurences DESC,REP.MostRecentApptDate DESC) AS Rank
  FROM (SELECT REF.MonthlyReferenceDate,
               PAT.ApptMonthlyDate, 
               REF.MaxMonthlyReferenceDateHistory,
               PAT.MostRecentApptDate,       
               PAT.Patient,
               PAT.Provider,
               PAT.PatientProviderOccurences        
          FROM bu_datalake.ReferenceDate REF
          JOIN (SELECT TRUNC(ApptDate,'MM') As ApptMonthlyDate,        
                       Patient,                                
                       Provider,                               
                       MAX(ApptDate) MostRecentApptDate,       
                       COUNT(*) PatientProviderOccurences      
                  FROM bu_datalake.PatientProvider             
                 GROUP BY TRUNC(ApptDate,'MM'),Patient,Provider) PAT
         WHERE PAT.ApptMonthlyDate BETWEEN REF.MaxMonthlyReferenceDateHistory AND REF.MonthlyReferenceDate
         ORDER BY REF.MonthlyReferenceDate,PAT.Patient,PAT.Provider) REP;
 
MonthlyReferenceDate    Patient Provider    PatientProviderOccurences   Rank
2022-01-01            A       BOB         1                         1
2022-02-01            A       BOB         1                         1
2022-03-01            A       BOB         3                         1
```

And finally I will apply a FILTER (Rank=1) only to show the results I need:

```
SELECT MonthlyReferenceDate,
       Patient,
       Provider,
       PatientProviderOccurences
FROM        
(
SELECT REP.MonthlyReferenceDate,
       REP.Patient,
       REP.Provider,
       REP.PatientProviderOccurences,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY REP.MonthlyReferenceDate ORDER BY REP.PatientProviderOccurences DESC,REP.MostRecentApptDate DESC) AS Rank
  FROM (SELECT REF.MonthlyReferenceDate,
               PAT.ApptMonthlyDate, 
               REF.MaxMonthlyReferenceDateHistory,
               PAT.MostRecentApptDate,       
               PAT.Patient,
               PAT.Provider,
               PAT.PatientProviderOccurences        
          FROM bu_datalake.ReferenceDate REF
          JOIN (SELECT TRUNC(ApptDate,'MM') As ApptMonthlyDate,        
                       Patient,                                
                       Provider,                               
                       MAX(ApptDate) MostRecentApptDate,       
                       COUNT(*) PatientProviderOccurences      
                  FROM bu_datalake.PatientProvider             
                 GROUP BY TRUNC(ApptDate,'MM'),Patient,Provider) PAT
         WHERE PAT.ApptMonthlyDate BETWEEN REF.MaxMonthlyReferenceDateHistory AND REF.MonthlyReferenceDate
         ORDER BY REF.MonthlyReferenceDate,PAT.Patient,PAT.Provider) REP
)
WHERE RANK =1
ORDER BY MonthlyReferenceDate

MonthlyReferenceDate    Patient Provider    PatientProviderOccurences
2022-01-01            A       BOB         1
2022-02-01            A       BOB         1
2022-03-01            A       BOB         3
2022-04-01            A       BOB         3
2022-05-01            A       BOB         3
2022-06-01            A       BOB         3
2022-07-01            A       JANE      3
2022-08-01            A       JANE      3
2022-09-01            A       JANE      3
2022-10-01            A       JANE      3
2022-11-01            A       JANE      3
2022-12-01            A       JANE      3
```

I hope these queries could help you solve your problem. Depending on your database, perhaps the functions to be applied need to be different.

Comment: And SQL Server doesn't have a `string` datatype.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Dale. I have updated the answer with a detailed explanation now. I have used a HIVE "database" to solve this problem, but I think you can do all the necessary changes to adapt these SQL commands (example: using VARCHAR than STRING types). Best regards,

Comment: You're still not using SQL Server syntax though.

Comment: Hi Dale ! For a pure SQL SERVER solution, I don't think there is a better explanation than that provided by Patrick.
But thinking about a slightly more agnostic approach that uses ANSI SQL, maybe the example I gave will be of some help for others users. Thanks for your feedback ! Best regards